# HP fanfic in which Vernon killed the real Harry and Dumbledore stole a child to replace him

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a Harry Potter fanfiction that I read a few years ago in which it turns out that Harry Potter isn't actually Harry Potter, but a child who was stolen from Diagon Alley to replace Harry Potter.

In this fanfiction, Vernon Dursley killed the real Harry Potter, and Dumbledore has been stealing, memory-replacing, and disguising wizarding children to replace Harry Potter as Vernon keeps killing the replacements. The current Harry Potter has all these memories from the past replacements, and some of the actions don't match up, which is how they find out that there are more dead little boys who had been stolen to replace Harry Potter. I think Harry Potter may have actually been a Malfoy/some other dark pureblood in this one, and had been under a glamour (to avoid being attacked due to his parentage) when he was stolen from Diagon Alley.

Could anyone help me find this story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it [*What You Learn From Spying*](https://fanfiction.net/s/12886958/1/What-You-Learn-From-Spying) by elvirakitties?

In this story, the current Harry Potter is Malfoy’s twin.

> "So we think the real Harry was killed by the muggles."

...

> "You know it might explain why Draco was so focused on you last year. The twin bond would have been pulling at him, he would remember it. You wouldn't if your memories were erased or blocked with a Memory Charm. An Obliviate would just remove the event not change years of memories."
>
> "I think I had flashes when I saw Draco. I know I did when I saw Diagon Alley, that was where I was taken from, I remembered the bookstore and I got scared when we entered it, it took me a few minutes to recover from it, I just thought it was a weird feeling and moved forward."

...

> "Now remember, Mr. Dursley, you can't just go keep killing the boys. I can't have too many go missing."

Comment: I think this might be the one! I think I read it on AO3, since I remember it being in chapters, but it definitely looks familiar! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A possible match is ["Will the Real Harry Potter Stand Up"](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12871056/1/Will-The-Real-Harry-Potter-Stand-Up)

> What if Harry Potter wasn't the first Harry Potter? What happened to the real Harry? What will happen to the fake Harry?

The real Harry Potter was killed by Vernon (and his replacement is in poor shape when Snape and Voldemort show up to rescue him). And he is a pureblood, Snape's son Steffan. What does not match up is that there's only one replacement.

Found with a search for `fanfiction "harry * replacement" vernon killed`.

Comment: I have read this one before, but unfortunately it's not the one I'm searching for. I think the one I'm looking for is multichaptered, and I definitely remember Harry having multiple sets of implanted memories from the previous Harry's.